# how to check value in list empty or not and if not get the value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am getting a list from servers like this

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2022-10-21",
    "Wages": [
      {
        "Name": "101 Working hours",
        "Balance": "8.00",
        "Date": "2022-10-21",
        "ShiftName": "AU128"
      },
      {
        "Name": "102 Bonus pay",
        "Balance": "3:48",
        "Date": "2022-10-21",
        "ShiftName": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "110 Split Shift",
        "Balance": "1:00",
        "Date": "2022-10-21",
        "ShiftName": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "111 Wage reduction",
        "Balance": "1:00",
        "Date": "2022-10-21",
        "ShiftName": ""
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to get ShiftName if it is not empty and shows at FE. shift name is in Wages List

```
Text(
  Wages[i].shiftName ?? "",
  style: wageTextStyle,
),
```

I try to use `List.any((any) => any.containsValue());`

but I do not know which value I get from server because shiftName can be changed

my API calling method from provider Consumer

```
            Consumer<EmployeeWageAccountsProvider>(
              builder: (context, data, child) {
              if (!data.isLoading) {
              int length = data.getEmployeeAccountsData!.length;
              if (data.getEmployeeAccountsData!.isNotEmpty) {
                wageAccountsData = data.getEmployeeAccountsData!;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return WageAccountsCard(
                      date: Helper.formatStringDate(
                          wageAccountsData[i].date!),
                     shiftName: wageAccountsData[i].wages! 
         [i].shiftName!.isEmpty ? "":wageAccountsData[i].wages! 
               [i].shiftName,
                     wages: wageAccountsData[i].wages,
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
              return noDataFound(context, 50);
            }
            return const WageAccountsShimmer();
          }),
```

wage accounts card to displaying data to user

```
 class WageAccountsCard extends StatelessWidget {
   final String? date;
   final String? shiftName;
   final List<Wages>? wages;

  const WageAccountsCard(
      {Key? key,
       this.date,
       this.shiftName,
       this.wages})
       : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
       decoration: CustomBoxDecoration.cardDecoration(context, 
       shadow: true),
     child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
       children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            shiftName ?? "",
            style: wageTextStyle,
          ),
          Text(
            date.toString(),
            style: wageTextStyle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: Styles.height(context) * 0.01,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            S.of(context).wage_type,
            style: cTextStyle,
          ),
          Text(
            S.of(context).balance,
            style: cTextStyle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      ]
  ),
);
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`shiftName ?? "",` used to return default value on null case.

You are getting empty String, therefore you can do

```dart
shiftName.isEmpty ? "onEmptyCaseValue" : shiftName
```

Comment: Showing issue refers to range error , you can try with `"${wageAccountsData[i].wages}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
return shiftName.isEmpty ? Center(child: Text('Empty')) : Text(
  shiftName ?? "",
  style: wageTextStyle,
),
```

Comment: still get the error

Comment: print [i value] you will find that i is grater then 0,1. we have only 2 vaule at postioon 0 and 1 but you are accessing at postion 2

Comment: in item : wageAccountsData.length

Comment: put this one and your probleam will be sloved

Comment: i have add it but still range error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249247/discussion-between-amit-flutter-and-arslan).

Answer (score 0):

```
wageAccountsData[i].wages! 
         [i].shiftName!.isEmpty ? "":wageAccountsData[i].wages[i].shiftName,
```

insted of this just write like this

```
wageAccountsData[i].wages![i].shiftName ?? "Default Text",
```

Comment: i have attack responses, kindly check it